# Что случилось с темами на github?

Tags: github

GitHub стал показывать только малую долю репозиториев по *темам* (/topics/).
Штук 10 максимум, хотя ранее было неограниченное количество (сколько существует репозиториев в данным тэгом)

Это изменение политики или моя проблема?

Почистил cache, cookie, проверил с разных браузеров и ничего не поменялось.

Пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ранее тех. поддержка GitHub дала следующий ответ:

> Thank you for writing in to GitHub Support and I'm sorry you have experienced this problem.
>   We have had a few reports of this bug and our engineers are looking into it. It's
>   very useful for us to have more data points, so thank you for submitting this report! 
>   I'll pass it on to the team.
>   I can't make any promises around specific changes or updates, but please trust that
>   your report is in good hands.

На 21.11.2019 проблема была решена.